# PL/ SQL Loop No data found

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I tried to take values for VarNewIdOne as a bulk collection. So i got values to bulk collection after i tried to equel that values to another variable (VarOldLevlIdOne) then getting out put as a NO data found.

```
            SELECT ITEM_ID bulk collect INTO VarNewIdOne
            FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS
            WHERE  PARENT_ITEM_ID = VarId;

  FOR k IN VarNewIdOne.First ..VarNewIdOne.Last LOOP

   SELECT LEVEL_ID  INTO VarOldLevlIdOne  
   FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS
   WHERE  ITEM_ID IN (VarNewIdOne(K));


 DELETE  FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS WHERE LEVEL_ID=VarOldLevlIdOne;

END LOOP;
```

These are my tables

```
    CREATE TABLE  "ITEMS" 
   (    "ITEM_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SHORT_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "HS_CODE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BRAND_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CAT_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "XMLCOL" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
    "REMARKS" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "VARIANT_TEMP_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "TRANS_DATE" DATE, 
    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "VERSION_ID" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "PARENT_ITEM_ID" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "ITEM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ITEM_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )


CREATE TABLE  "ITEM_UOM_LEVELS" 
   (    "LEVEL_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ITEM_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CONV_FACTR" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "IMAGE" BLOB, 
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "XMLCOL" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
    "UOM_LEVEL" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LONG_NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UOM_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SYS_USAGE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UOM_LEVEL_VOLUME" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "ITEM_LEVEL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("LEVEL_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
ALTER TABLE  "ITEM_UOM_LEVELS" ADD CONSTRAINT "ITM_UOM_LEVELS_ITEM_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ITEM_ID")
      REFERENCES  "ITEMS" ("ITEM_ID") ENABLE
```

sample data

```
insert into ITEMS   (Item_Id,   Name,   Short_Name, Code,   Hs_Code_Id, Brand_Id,   Cat_Id  ,Remarks    ,Variant_Temp Id,   Parent_Item_Id) values (203,"small Large updated","SML_LRG","SML_LRGBYPO123",   111,    8,  5,      "Comment",4,202);

   insert into ITEM_UOM_LEVELS (LEVEL_ID,ITEM_ID,CONV_FACTR,STATUS_ID,UOM_LEVEL,    LONG_NAME,UOM_ID,SYS_USAGE_ID,UOM_LEVEL_VOLUME) values (61,71,"Cost",1, 1,"Test",9,1,30)
```

Comment: could you give us your table definition and sample data please, it might be that none of your data is actually adhering to all of these where conditions so in the end there is no result

Comment: Clarify your question, it's a little unclear

Comment: You loop through VarNewId, but you don't access it anywhere inside the loop. Maybe you got confused with your array names?

Comment: We still don't have any table data so we can't know if the query returns anything (I mean the values in your tables, your records)

Comment: ITEM_UOM_LEVELS can contain several entries for one ITEM_ID. Which LEVEL_ID would be the one you want to retrieve and delete from ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS then?

Comment: And do you really want to delete from ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS where LEVEL_ID = xxx, no matter what item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously table ITEM_UOM_LEVELS sometimes has no entry for an ITEM_ID and thus results in a NO DATA FOUND error. So use a subselect instead:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID bulk collect INTO VarNewIdOne
FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS
WHERE  PARENT_ITEM_ID = VarId;

FOR k IN VarNewIdOne.First ..VarNewIdOne.Last LOOP
  DELETE  FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS WHERE LEVEL_ID IN
  (
    SELECT LEVEL_ID  
    FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS
    WHERE  ITEM_ID = VarNewIdOne(K)
  );
END LOOP;
```

Or even make this a single SQL statement:

```
DELETE  FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS WHERE LEVEL_ID IN
(
  SELECT LEVEL_ID  
  FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS
  WHERE  ITEM_ID IN
  (
    SELECT ITEM_ID
    FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS
    WHERE  PARENT_ITEM_ID = VarId
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01403: no data found` occurs when the **filter predicate** in your SELECT statement is unable to retrieve any rows based on the condition.

> WHERE  ITEM_ID IN (VarNewIdOne(K))

If there is no matching ITEM_ID then **no data found** exception will be raised.

For example,

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    cnt NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT empno FROM emp
  6    )
  7    LOOP
  8      SELECT empno INTO cnt FROM emp WHERE empno = 1234;
  9    END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 8


SQL>
```

Comment: I'm retrieving data to VarNewIdOne in first select                               SELECT ITEM_ID bulk collect INTO VarNewIdOne
                FROM   BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS
                WHERE  PARENT_ITEM_ID = VarId;            but after come inside of For loop in facing that problem

Comment: @user3359056 And that is what I said. In your loop, the select into query is not fetching any rows because there is no matching row for `ITEM_ID IN (VarNewIdOne(K))`

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to avoid explicit looping logic where you can. In this case you can replace the bulk collect and loop with a single statement:

```
DELETE FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVEL_CONTROLS c
  WHERE c.LEVEL_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT l.LEVEL_ID
                         FROM BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEMS i
                         INNER JOIN BIZZXE_V2_SCH.ITEM_UOM_LEVELS l
                           ON l.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
                         WHERE i.PARENT_ITEM_ID = VarId);
```

Best of luck.